# Remove specific set of event listeners from an HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove only the `mouseup` event listners from a selected HTML element.

I used the below code but it will remove  all listners.

```
var old_element = divs[d];
                var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
                old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);
```

this is how i attach event listners.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('body');// to enhance the preformance
for(var d in divs) { 
        try{             
            if (divs[d].addEventListener) {
                 divs[d].addEventListener('mouseup',callHighlight);
            } else {
                divs[d].attachEvent('mouseup', callHighlight);
            } 
        }catch(err){
            //alert(err.message);
        }
}
```

Comment: It won't remove inline listeners, nor those added using *attachEvent* in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) instead of replacechild which will obviously remove all events.

```
 old_element.removeEventListener('mouseup', handler);
```

Comment: I used that also. But in my code there were several `mouseup`  events. I add several `mouseup` listeners to an element. Will your code remove all of those?

Comment: That only works if a reference to the listener function is available to pass to *removeEventListener*, so it won't work where a function expression is used in the assignment.

Comment: Yup how are you attaching the events? if you use anonymous function instead of a func reference this wont work.  Show your event attachment part, are you using attributes?

Comment: @PSL i showed the event attachment part in my original question.

Comment: @vidudaya Yes you can use `callHighlight` in the removeListened. See the example in the fiddle in my prev comment.

Comment: @PSL well i  don't know how many event listners will be added. and all function names will  be same. So how can i handle them.

Comment: @vidudaya What do you mean by `all function names will be same`?

Answer (score 1):

When cloning an element, listeners added using *addEventListener* or by direct property assignment (`element.onclick = fn;`) are removed, but in–line listeners and those added using IE's *attachEvent* are not.

In your scenario where listeners are added by reference and also possibly using *attachEvent*, you are best to remove them using *removeEventListener* and *detachEvent*. So you might like to create add and remove functions like:

```
function addEvent(element, event, fn) {
  if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
  } else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + event, fn);
  }
}

function removeEvent(element, event, fn) {
  if (element.removeEventListener) {
    element.removeEventListener(event, fn);
  } else if (element.detachEvent) {
    element.detachEvent('on' + event, fn);
  }
}
```

Note that there are some significant differences between *addEventListener* and *attachEvent*, the most important are that in the latter, *this* is not set to the element whose handler is calling the function and a reference to the event isn't passed as the first argument to the listener. So the listener function ends up looking like:

```
function foo(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  ...
}
```

There are ways around this, but they introduce more issues. Keep it simple if you can.

Comment: Looks like using solely `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` is the way to go in the modern world: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener https://caniuse.com/#search=removeeventlistener

Answer (score 0):

By default all event listeners are null, so simply just reset it. Problem is that all your mouseup events are registered to the body, so therefore you won't be able to drop the event without first stopping the event from bubbling to the body. You can solve that problem with, `stopPropagation()`

```
 old_element.onmouseup = function (e) {
   // event won't go up to the body tag
   e.stopPropagation();
   return null;
 };
```

or

```
 function kill (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  return null; 
 }

 old_element.onmouseup = kill;
 second_element.onmouseup = kill;
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKAg5/1/)

Comment: The OP is attaching listeners using *addEventListener* and *attachEvent*. Assignment to the related property does not overwrite such listeners.

Comment: @RobG see when you say that i get confused, bc it works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKAg5/2/)